# There is no Credit/Debit Card on the Apple Online Store associated with your Apple ID

Tags: apple-id, developer-program, itunes-store, apple-pay

When visiting `developer.apple.com` to renew my Apple Developer Program membership, I see the following error:

[image: error message quoted below]

> There is no credit/debit card on the Apple Online Store associated with your Apple ID to auto-renew your membership.
>
> Add a credit/debit card to maintain membership benefits and keep your apps available on the App Store.
>
> Add Card

or

> The credit/debit card associated with your Apple ID on the Apple Online Store is expired.
>
> Update your credit/debit card to maintain membership benefits and keep your apps available on the App Store.
>
> Update Card

When I click "Add Card", I am taken to `appleid.apple.com`.

But when I go to edit the Payment & Shipping information, **my details are grayed out and cannot be edited**. "Apple Pay" is possibly selected, and I see no way to add a new Credit Card.

How do I add a credit card?

Comment: for the surprising amount of people finding and upvoting this question: are your details grayed out too? I was thinking that was a rare problem for my account, but maybe it's everyone.

Comment: This is still an annoying issue. The Apple Developer page tells me to use iTunes (not Music), but when I visit my payment settings there, I _do have_ my credit card set up. :shrug:

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I talked to Apple Support on the phone. They directed me to visit the url:

> https://www.apple.com/shop/browse/account/home

Under "Account Settings", click "Shipping and billing".

This brings you to a much older Apple website, still styled with [aqua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqua_(user_interface)) controls!

> https://secure1.store.apple.com/shop/account/setup_default

I was able to add a new credit card on this site.

When I return to the Developer Program site, the red banner has gone away.

Comment: THANK YOU! Been searching for a while. Apple just loves messing with developers

Comment: The first 20 times I tried to log into the old site it appeared not to work with two factor authentication.  (I got the prompt on my phone but the login box did not proceed to ask for the code).  Some combination of trying both the URLs above many times finally resolved it and I was able to get in.

Comment: It finally works for me. It does not provide an option to change the billing address from the United States to another country. So I change the URL by adding country code after ".com/"

Comment: Thank you! Apple really amazes me sometimes how it makes the easy things hard

Comment: This is absolutely baffling. Why are they making it so hard to take my money?